# Batch File System cannot find file after Loop

Tags: batch-file, label, goto

I am creating a batch file to open remote Computer Management console by taking User ID as input and computer name from 2nd column from file data.csv. it works fine on first attempt. When it goes back to :start label. and ask for other input. it gives error. System cannot find file ./data.csv 
My code is

```
 :start
    set /p Input="Enter User-ID:" 

    for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (".\data.csv") do (
       if %input% ==%%a ("cmd /c Start /B /wait compmgmt.msc –a /computer=%%b")

    )
    cls
    GOTO start
```

Comment: Why are you using `cmd /C` and `start`? and why are you quoting the entire command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice to use %~dp0 for paths in batch files (instead of relative paths like .)  that way if the current working folder changes the file will always be located.

So change to %~dp0data.csv

Comment: The dot could as well refer to %CD% by intention. But neither should change on the way in the code shown. To choose a fixed (non relative) path is the better option.

Comment: Waoooooooooo Perfect Thank you Joe. Fantastic.

Comment: Dear one more problem. I've to make it exe file. so when i change it to exe it does not work. but when open .bat it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
:start
set /p Input="Enter User-ID:" 
PUSHD    
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (".\data.csv") do (
 if %input% ==%%a ("cmd /c Start /B /wait compmgmt.msc –a /computer=%%b")

)
POPD
cls
GOTO start
```

should restore sanity, pushing the directory then restoring it before the next cycle.